# Php not getting full url when post data

Tags: php

Is there any way to change url $_GET Delimiter `&` to other symbol. I'm trying to get multiple values from url. url is in this form `https://example.com/?url=posturl&key=postkey&other=postother;` Everthing is getting properly but the problem is that there is one paramater name `&signature=randomstring`  but i'm unable get full url `&signature=randomstring` will be removed from url.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="customUrl" value="'. $finbase.'/?mpdurl='.$hlsurl.'&mpdkey='.$mpdkey.'&customval='.$customval.'&customdata='.$customdata.'"
```

orignal url 
https://example.com/widevine/license?custom_data=eyJjYV9zeXN0ZW0iOiJodHMjV9&signature=b6KNZ%2ftxUqugFJ155Lp1RA7BonM%3d

Comment: Is the signature parameter coming after the url parameter? If so change the order and see if that fixes it

Comment: i can't change the order its widevine url inside drm

Comment: Why do you have two `?`? That could be a problem

Comment: I correct my question.

Comment: Doesn't seems a problem to me. Where is your code?

Comment: When posting mpdkey there is one parameter `&signature=randomstring` the url not shown from here `&signature=randomstring`

Comment: Don't post code as comment. Update your question with all relevant code.

Comment: Updated my question. Now please check.

Comment: There are a lot of variables in there. Where does these came from? Where is `&signature` in your code? Where exactly is the problem in this code?

Comment: If the parameter is literally called `&signature`, which would be really, really, really weird, then it would probably get encoded to `%26signature`. However, the best thing to do is dump `$_GET` and see what's in there.

Comment: There is one input name mpdkey and their value is url format shown on code above 
 and inside that url there is one parameter `&signature`.

Comment: Same result signature is removed

Comment: Is there any way to solve it using regex ? If so please help i'm still getting same results.